# EBNF: "multiple variables = value"

Tags: ebnf

Now I have

```
A = a;
B = a;
C = a;
```

Can I instead do

```
A , B , C = a;
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = A | B | C?
```

EBNF usually works that way.

Comment: Well, perhaps; my thought was to help turning "baby EBNF" to smth. more real.

Answer (score 0):

No; any given rule can only have one item on the left side.